# WMI Remote Process Starting

Tags: c#, process, wmi

#### Scenario

I've written a WMI Wrapper that seems to be quite sufficient, however whenever I run the code to start a remote process on a server, I see the process name appear in the task manager but the process itself does not start like it should (as in, I don't see the command line log window of the process that prints out what it's doing etc.)
The process I am trying to start is just a C# application executable that I have written.
Below is my WMI Wrapper Code and the code I am using to start running the process.

#### Question

Is the process actually running? - Even if it is only displaying the process name in the task manager and not actually launching the application to the users window?

#### Code To Start The Process

```
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("InsertServerName");
        WMIWrapper wrapper = new WMIWrapper("Insert User Name", "Insert Password",  hostEntry.HostName);
         List<Process> processes = wrapper.GetProcesses();
         foreach (Process process in processes)
         {
             if (process.Caption.Equals("MyAppName.exe"))
             {
                Console.WriteLine(process.Caption);
                Console.WriteLine(process.CommandLine);
                int processId;
                wrapper.StartProcess("E:\\MyData\\Data\\MyAppName.exe", out processId);
                Console.WriteLine(processId.ToString());
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

#### WMI Wrapper Code

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Management;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using Common.WMI.Objects;
 using System.Net;

 namespace Common.WMIWrapper
 {
 public class WMIWrapper : IDisposable
 {
    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the wrapper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="username"></param>
    /// <param jobName="password"></param>
    /// <param jobName="server"></param>
    public WMIWrapper(string server)
    {
        Initialise(server);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the wrapper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="username"></param>
    /// <param jobName="password"></param>
    /// <param jobName="server"></param>
    public WMIWrapper(string username, string password, string server)
    {
        Initialise(username, password, server);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Destructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up unmanaged references
    /// </summary>
    ~WMIWrapper()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Initialise

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise the WMI Connection (local machine)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="server"></param>
    private void Initialise(string server)
    {
        m_server = server;

        // set connection options
        m_connectOptions = new ConnectionOptions();

        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise the WMI connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="username">Username to connect to server with</param>
    /// <param jobName="password">Password to connect to server with</param>
    /// <param jobName="server">Server to connect to</param>
    private void Initialise(string username, string password, string server)
    {
        m_server = server;
        
        // set connection options
        m_connectOptions = new ConnectionOptions();

        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName);

        if (host.HostName.Equals(server, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;

        
        m_connectOptions.Username = username;
        m_connectOptions.Password = password;
        m_connectOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        m_connectOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;            
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a list of available wmi namespaces
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<String> GetWMINamespaces()
    {
        ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root",  this.Server), this.ConnectionOptions);
        List<String> wmiNamespaceList = new List<String>();

        ManagementClass wmiNamespaces = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("__namespace"), null); ;

        foreach (ManagementObject ns in wmiNamespaces.GetInstances())
            wmiNamespaceList.Add(ns["Name"].ToString());

        return wmiNamespaceList;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a list of available classes in a namespace
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="wmiNameSpace">Namespace to get wmi classes for</param>
    /// <returns>List of classes in the requested namespace</returns>
    public List<String> GetWMIClassList(string wmiNameSpace)
    {
        ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\{1}", this.Server, wmiNameSpace), this.ConnectionOptions);
        List<String> wmiClasses = new List<String>();

        ManagementObjectSearcher wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM meta_Class"), null);

        foreach (ManagementClass wmiClass in wmiSearcher.Get())
            wmiClasses.Add(wmiClass["__CLASS"].ToString());

        return wmiClasses;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of wmi properties for the specified class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="wmiNameSpace">WMI Namespace</param>
    /// <param jobName="wmiClass">WMI Class</param>
    /// <returns>List of properties for the class</returns>
    public List<String> GetWMIClassPropertyList(string wmiNameSpace, string wmiClass)
    {
        List<String> wmiClassProperties = new List<string>();

        ManagementClass managementClass = GetWMIClass(wmiNameSpace, wmiClass);

        foreach (PropertyData property in managementClass.Properties)
            wmiClassProperties.Add(property.Name);

        return wmiClassProperties;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of methods for the class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="wmiNameSpace"></param>
    /// <param jobName="wmiClass"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<String> GetWMIClassMethodList(string wmiNameSpace, string wmiClass)
    {
        List<String> wmiClassMethods = new List<string>();


        ManagementClass managementClass = GetWMIClass(wmiNameSpace, wmiClass);

        foreach (MethodData method in managementClass.Methods)
            wmiClassMethods.Add(method.Name);

        return wmiClassMethods;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the specified management class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="wmiNameSpace">Namespace of the class</param>
    /// <param jobName="wmiClass">Type of the class</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ManagementClass GetWMIClass(string wmiNameSpace, string wmiClass)
    {
        ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\{1}", this.Server, wmiNameSpace), this.ConnectionOptions);
        ManagementClass managementClass = null;

        ManagementObjectSearcher wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, new WqlObjectQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM meta_Class WHERE __CLASS = '{0}'", wmiClass)), null);

        foreach (ManagementClass wmiObject in wmiSearcher.Get())
            managementClass = wmiObject;

        return managementClass;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an instance of the specficied class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="wmiNameSpace">Namespace of the classes</param>
    /// <param jobName="wmiClass">Type of the classes</param>
    /// <returns>Array of management classes</returns>
    public ManagementObject[] GetWMIClassObjects(string wmiNameSpace, string wmiClass)
    {
        ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\{1}", this.Server, wmiNameSpace), this.ConnectionOptions);
        List<ManagementObject> wmiClasses = new List<ManagementObject>();

        ManagementObjectSearcher wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, new WqlObjectQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", wmiClass)), null);

        foreach (ManagementObject wmiObject in wmiSearcher.Get())
            wmiClasses.Add(wmiObject);

        return wmiClasses.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a full list of services
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Service> GetServices()
    {
        return GetService(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of services
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Service> GetService(string name)
    {
        ManagementObject[] services = GetWMIClassObjects("CIMV2", "WIN32_Service");
        List<Service> serviceList = new List<Service>();

        for (int i = 0; i < services.Length; i++)
        {
            ManagementObject managementObject = services[i];
            Service service = new Service(managementObject);
            service.Status = (string)managementObject["Status"];
            service.Name = (string)managementObject["Name"];
            service.DisplayName = (string)managementObject["DisplayName"];
            service.PathName = (string)managementObject["PathName"];
            service.ProcessId = (uint)managementObject["ProcessId"];
            service.Started = (bool)managementObject["Started"];
            service.StartMode = (string)managementObject["StartMode"];
            service.ServiceType = (string)managementObject["ServiceType"];
            service.InstallDate = (string)managementObject["InstallDate"];
            service.Description = (string)managementObject["Description"];
            service.Caption = (string)managementObject["Caption"];

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || name.Equals(service.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                serviceList.Add(service);
        }

        return serviceList;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of processes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Process> GetProcesses()
    {
        return GetProcess(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of processes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Process> GetProcess(uint? processId)
    {
        ManagementObject[] processes = GetWMIClassObjects("CIMV2", "WIN32_Process");
        List<Process> processList = new List<Process>();

        for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
        {
            ManagementObject managementObject = processes[i];
            Process process = new Process(managementObject);
            process.Priority = (uint)managementObject["Priority"];
            process.ProcessId = (uint)managementObject["ProcessId"];
            process.Status = (string)managementObject["Status"];

            DateTime createDate;

            if (ConvertFromWmiDate((string)managementObject["CreationDate"], out  createDate))                
                process.CreationDate = createDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            

            process.Caption = (string)managementObject["Caption"];
            process.CommandLine = (string)managementObject["CommandLine"];
            process.Description = (string)managementObject["Description"];
            process.ExecutablePath = (string)managementObject["ExecutablePath"];
            process.ExecutionState = (string)managementObject["ExecutionState"];
            process.MaximumWorkingSetSize = (UInt32?)managementObject ["MaximumWorkingSetSize"];
            process.MinimumWorkingSetSize = (UInt32?)managementObject["MinimumWorkingSetSize"];
            process.KernelModeTime = (UInt64)managementObject["KernelModeTime"];
            process.ThreadCount = (UInt32)managementObject["ThreadCount"];
            process.UserModeTime = (UInt64)managementObject["UserModeTime"];
            process.VirtualSize = (UInt64)managementObject["VirtualSize"];
            process.WorkingSetSize = (UInt64)managementObject["WorkingSetSize"];

            if (processId == null || process.ProcessId == processId.Value)
                processList.Add(process);
        }

        return processList;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start the specified process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="commandLine"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool StartProcess(string command, out int processId)
    {
        processId = int.MaxValue;

        ManagementClass processClass = GetWMIClass("CIMV2", "WIN32_Process");           
        
        object[] objectsIn = new object[4];
        objectsIn[0] = command;

        processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", objectsIn);

        if (objectsIn[3] == null)
            return false;

        processId = int.Parse(objectsIn[3].ToString());

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Schedule a process on the remote machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    /// <param name="scheduleTime"></param>
    /// <param name="jobName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool ScheduleProcess(string command, DateTime scheduleTime, out string jobName)
    {
        jobName = String.Empty;

        ManagementClass scheduleClass = GetWMIClass("CIMV2", "Win32_ScheduledJob");

        object[] objectsIn = new object[7];

        objectsIn[0] = command;

        objectsIn[1] = String.Format("********{0:00}{1:00}{2:00}.000000+060", scheduleTime.Hour, scheduleTime.Minute, scheduleTime.Second);
        objectsIn[5] = true;

        scheduleClass.InvokeMethod("Create", objectsIn);

        if (objectsIn[6] == null)
            return false;

        UInt32 scheduleid = (uint)objectsIn[6];

        jobName = scheduleid.ToString();

        return true;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the current time on the remote server
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DateTime Now()
    {
        ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\{1}", this.Server, "CIMV2"), this.ConnectionOptions);
        ManagementClass managementClass = null;

        ManagementObjectSearcher wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, new WqlObjectQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime")), null);

        DateTime localTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        foreach (ManagementObject time in wmiSearcher.Get())
        {
            UInt32 day = (UInt32)time["Day"];
            UInt32 month = (UInt32)time["Month"];
            UInt32 year = (UInt32)time["Year"];
            UInt32 hour = (UInt32)time["Hour"];
            UInt32 minute = (UInt32)time["Minute"];
            UInt32 second = (UInt32)time["Second"];
            localTime = new DateTime((int)year, (int)month, (int)day, (int)hour, (int)minute, (int)second);
        };



        return localTime;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a wmi date into a proper date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="wmiDate">Wmi formatted date</param>
    /// <returns>Date time object</returns>
    private static bool ConvertFromWmiDate(string wmiDate, out DateTime properDate)
    {
        properDate = DateTime.MinValue;

        string properDateString;

        // check if string is populated
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(wmiDate))
            return false;

        wmiDate = wmiDate.Trim().ToLower().Replace("*", "0");

        string[] months = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

        try
        {
            properDateString = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}.{6}",
                wmiDate.Substring(6, 2), months[int.Parse(wmiDate.Substring(4, 2)) - 1], wmiDate.Substring(0, 4), wmiDate.Substring(8, 2), wmiDate.Substring(10, 2), wmiDate.Substring(12, 2), wmiDate.Substring(15, 6));
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // try and parse the new date
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(properDateString, out properDate))
            return false;

        // true if conversion successful
        return true;
    }


    private bool m_disposed;

    #region IDisposable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Managed dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose of managed and unmanaged objects
    /// </summary>
    /// <param jobName="disposing"></param>
    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            m_connectOptions = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    private ConnectionOptions m_connectOptions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the management scope
    /// </summary>
    private ConnectionOptions ConnectionOptions
    {
        get
        {
            return m_connectOptions;
        }
        set
        {
            m_connectOptions = value;
        }
    }

    private String m_server;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the server to connect to
    /// </summary>
    public String Server
    {
        get
        {
            return m_server;
        }
        set
        {
            m_server = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is running but it's not running interactive. If you're running a process remotely you can't be sure that someone is even logged in to that pc so you can't assume that it can have a GUI that a user can interact with.

I'd suggest, instead of writing progress to the console window, write it to a file or the Event log.