# Start a process using wmi on a remote computer

Tags: c++, wmi, remote-desktop

I used this code provided on msdn to connect to remote computer to check processes, but I don't understand how to start a process on remote PC using wmi in c++.

```
IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

// Get the user name and password for the remote computer
CREDUI_INFO cui;
bool useToken = false;
bool useNTLM = true;
wchar_t pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1] = {0};
wchar_t pszPwd[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1] = {0};
wchar_t pszDomain[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
wchar_t pszUserName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
wchar_t pszAuthority[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
BOOL fSave;
DWORD dwErr;

memset(&cui,0,sizeof(CREDUI_INFO));
cui.cbSize = sizeof(CREDUI_INFO);
cui.hwndParent = NULL;
// Ensure that MessageText and CaptionText identify
// what credentials to use and which application requires them.
cui.pszMessageText = TEXT("Press cancel to use process token");
cui.pszCaptionText = TEXT("Enter Account Information");
cui.hbmBanner = NULL;
fSave = FALSE;

dwErr = CredUIPromptForCredentials( 
    &cui,                             // CREDUI_INFO structure
    TEXT(""),                         // Target for credentials
    NULL,                             // Reserved
    0,                                // Reason
    pszName,                          // User name
    CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1,     // Max number for user name
    pszPwd,                           // Password
    CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1,     // Max number for password
    &fSave,                           // State of save check box
    CREDUI_FLAGS_GENERIC_CREDENTIALS |// flags
    CREDUI_FLAGS_ALWAYS_SHOW_UI |
    CREDUI_FLAGS_DO_NOT_PERSIST);  

if(dwErr == ERROR_CANCELLED)
{
    useToken = true;
}
else if (dwErr)
{
    cout << "Did not get credentials " << dwErr << endl;
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;      
}

// change the computerName strings below to the full computer name
// of the remote computer
if(!useNTLM)
{
    StringCchPrintf(pszAuthority, CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1, L"kERBEROS:%s", L"COMPUTERNAME");
}

// Connect to the remote root\cimv2 namespace
// and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
//---------------------------------------------------------

hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
    _bstr_t(L"\\\\COMPUTERNAME\\root\\cimv2"),
    _bstr_t(useToken?NULL:pszName),    // User name
    _bstr_t(useToken?NULL:pszPwd),     // User password
    NULL,                              // Locale             
    NULL,                              // Security flags
    _bstr_t(useNTLM?NULL:pszAuthority),// Authority        
    NULL,                              // Context object 
    &pSvc                              // IWbemServices proxy
    );

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                // Program has failed.
}
```

Comment: What is your question ? What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: The question below is similar to yours 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627810/wmi-remote-process-starting?rq=1

Comment: @Garf365 my question is how to start a process on remote PC using WMI in c++ code...

Comment: @shasanka If this is your question, you have written a duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37463644/4068240 and the code snippet in your questions body is not related to it.