# How to start a process on a remote server?

Tags: c#, server

I'm trying to start command prompt process, remotely to a server  and write a write a command to it and execute. The problem I have is that the process starts as background process.
Even tho, as a background process is possible to write a command into .cmd and execute it?

Hope I been explicit enough.

Here is my code.

```
var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
connection.Username = @"xxxx";
connection.Password = "xxxxx";


ManagementScope WMIscope = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", REMOTE_SERVER_NAME), connection);
WMIscope.Connect();

ManagementClass WMIprocess = new ManagementClass(WMIscope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());

object[] process = { "cmd.exe" };

object result = WMIprocess.InvokeMethod("Create", process);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WMI Remote Process Starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627810/wmi-remote-process-starting)

Comment: "the process starts as background process" - if by this, you mean it doesn't show up on a users desktop, then yes, that's expected. The remote command doesn't barge into someone else's session (if, indeed, there even is anyone logged in on the other machine)

Comment: Yes that I was ment @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Event tho as background process is posible to write a command in the cmd.exe and execute it?

Comment: Maybe, but I'd have to question why you're launching `cmd.exe` rather than *whatever program you actually want to run* and are instead going to force `cmd` to parse a command line apart to discover this detail?

Comment: Is not a program I want to run, will be a script for indexing files, witch every time will be different depending on some cases.